# C# How to read the visible text off chrome webpage

Tags: c#, google-chrome, ui-automation

I have used UIAutomation to try and get the visible text off google chrome, 
however chrome doesnt allow IsTextPatternAvailable. If there a way that I can read the text off a chrome web page using C# that doesnt depend on apps like selenium and not using chrome extensions...

Comment: I would suggest you to use selenium for Chrome. It's much easier and powerful with lots of features. 'Are you the real slim shady?'

Comment: As I mentioned in my description... NO selenium

Comment: I managed to get the IsTextPatternAvailable to be allowed. Go to chrome://accessibility and turn it on :)

Comment: I know your requirements specifically say no selenium but I agree with @SouvikGhosh. I have used UIA with edge and internet explorer before and found the experience to be less than pleasent compared to automating any other desktop application I have worked on. The web drivers for Chrome and Firefox are very good and marrionet is only getting better. As far as needing to install anything when I have used selenium with Chrome I only need the Chrome web driver DLL for my project and didnt have to do anything to Chrome itself to make it work.